# How to stich (merge, join, ...) multiple OData microservices together

Tags: c#, odata, microservices, api-gateway

we want to publish multiple datasources in our company via separate **OData microservices**. All these microservices shall be presented by **one API Gateway**. The gateway shall also stich the metadata together in order to look like **ONE** service.

I found the [FALCOR-project](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor) which looks like the way to go.

[image]

But it has one drawback: It must be OData-schema conform!
These microservices (or the API gateway) shall be used by third party applications like Power BI.

A "nice-to-have" is to maintain the links (nav properties) between these services in the gateway.